# leincljs build error : java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have just run `lein cljsbuild once` in my lein project directory, and I got the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException : Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var: clojure.tools.reader/resolve-symbol`

Stacktrace:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fyquah95/0a02b06c0a9aa2225f9c/raw/0cc05629a18c3711e27b1fc9dd59db0532d964b8/gistfile1.txt

My project.clj file:

```
(defproject barclays-cycle-hire-stats "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"                                                                                                                               
  :description "FIXME: write description"                                                                                                                                            
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"                                                                                                                                                    
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"                                                                                                                                           
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}                                                                                                                        
  :main barclays-cycle-hire-stats.core                                                                                                                                               
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.6"]                                                                                                                                                 
            [lein-ring "0.8.7"]]                                                                                                                                                     
  :source-paths ["src/clj"]                                                                                                                                                          
  :cljsbuild {                                                                                                                                                                       
    :builds [{:source-paths ["src/cljs"]                                                                                                                                             
              :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/main.js"                                                                                                                    
                         :optimizations :whitespace                                                                                                                                  
                         :pretty-print true}}]}                                                                                                                                      
  :dependencies [[http-kit "2.1.18"]                                                                                                                                                 
                 [reagent "0.5.1-rc"]                                                                                                                                                
                 [cljs-ajax "0.3.14"]                                                                                                                                                
                 [compojure "1.1.6"]                                                                                                                                                 
                 [hiccup "1.0.4"]                                                                                                                                                    
                 [org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.4"]                                                                                                                            
                 ; [org.clojure/clojure.core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]                                                                                                         
                 [spyscope "0.1.5"]                                                                                                                                                  
                 [org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.1.1"]                                                                                                                            
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]                                                                                                                                     
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]                                                                                                                                       
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.48" :exclusion [org.clojure/data.json]]                                                                                             
                 [org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.3"]]                                                                                                                                     
  :eval-in-leiningen true                                                                                                                                                            
  :ring {:handler barclays-cycle-hire-stats.routes/app})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without `:eval-in-leiningen true`.

`:eval-in-leiningen` is intended for plugins, and it's a source of weird errors when used in a project.

You can find information about `:eval-in-leiningen` and `:eval-in-project` in the [Project isolation](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/tree/master/leiningen-core#project-isolation) section of leiningen.core doc, and [Plugins](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PLUGINS.md#writing-a-plugin) doc of leiningen

Answer (score 0):

Adding :exclusions [org.apache.ant/ant] to clojurescript dependency fixed the same error message for me. So it looks like this:

```
[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.48" :exclusions [org.apache.ant/ant]]
```